# What's the correct way to say “French speaking people from Belgium”?

Tags: demande-de-mot

The website I'm building needs to distinguish between Dutch speaking customers from Belgium and French speaking customers from Belgium. I need to address both groups in their native language.

How would I formulate that correctly? 'Belgique Francophone'? 'Belgique Français'? Another way in the form of 'French speaking Belgians'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to do but :

- `Français (France)`
- `Français (Belgique)`
- `Français (Canada)`
- *etc* ...

is clear for Belgians and French if they go on your website.

Answer (score 7):

[Fabien's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11637/1129) focuses on a list of languages. However, you might be interested in showing the user a list of countries instead, with the language when disambiguation is needed:

> ...
>    België (Nederlands)
>    Belgique (Français)
>    ...
>    Canada (English)
>    Canada (Français)
>    ...
>    France
>    ...

You could even omit the language if the name of the country is spelled differently in each language, like *België*/*Belgique* for example. You'd still have to indicate the language for countries like *Canada*, which is spelled the same way in English and French. This is the approach used by [Apple](http://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/).

Others like [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/locale.aspx) prefer to always indicate the country, even if no disambiguation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Un (ou une) Belge francophone habite en général Bruxelles ou une partie de la région Wallone appelée souvent [Wallonie][1].

La Communauté française de Belgique<sup>1</sup> désigne les territoires  où le français est la langue administrative.

La communauté francophone Belge regroupe les locuteurs français.

Comment: Trouver un francophone (dont ce n'est pas nécessairement la langue maternelle) en Flandre est aisé. La division administrative est la [Communauté française de Belgique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communaut%C3%A9_fran%C3%A7aise_de_Belgique) (ne me demande pas qui a choisi ce nom surréaliste).

Comment: @Unfrancophone - Corrigé - Est une dénomination récente ? J'entends encore beaucoup de *Belgique francophone* dans la presse hexagonale.

Comment: C'est le terme employé dans la constitution depuis la création des communautés en tant qu'institution.  Le terme informel _Fédération Wallonie-Bruxelles_ donné par Wikipedia est plus récent, il n'était pas d'usage quand j'ai quitté la Belgique voici environ quinze ans.